# Finding the parent by the children, and the parent may have another parent to find with the use of streams API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream

I am trying to find the parent by using the child. I am not a pro on using streams, but I will say that I understand on an okay level. My problem is that I have child's entities and they have one parent, but the same parent can have a parent too and the same that parent has and etc.

Example:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
Parent parent;
```

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.lazy, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
```

```java
List<Child> children = child.getChildren().stream()
        .flatMap(c -> c.getChildren().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But for some reason, I can't reach the parent.
I want to go child -> parent -> parent etc till its no more left. And I also want to be able to see reach all children in every parent.

Comment: How would you do this without streams?

Comment: With a loop i guess? @LouisWasserman

Comment: so please try with loop 1st and try to convert in stream,1stly try to apply your thinking process how you are going to iterate